# How to get point, where line collides with buffered image or rectangle?

Tags: java, graphics, collision-detection, lines, rectangles

I am trying to draw line with some start position to some direction, but i want to stop the line on the point where the line collides with something like bufferedImage or rectangle. How to get that point?

```
public Point2D[] getIntersectionPoint(Line2D line, Rectangle2D rectangle)
{ 
Point2D[] p = new Point2D[4];
    Point2D[] p = new Point2D[4];

    // Top line
    p[0] = getIntersectionPoint(line,
                    new Line2D.Double(
                    rectangle.getX(),
                    rectangle.getY(),
                    rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth(),
                    rectangle.getY()));
    // Bottom line
    p[1] = getIntersectionPoint(line,
                    new Line2D.Double(
                    rectangle.getX(),
                    rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight(),
                    rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth(),
                    rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight()));
    // Left side...
    p[2] = getIntersectionPoint(line,
                    new Line2D.Double(
                    rectangle.getX(),
                    rectangle.getY(),
                    rectangle.getX(),
                    rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight()));
    // Right side
    p[3] = getIntersectionPoint(line,
                    new Line2D.Double(
                    rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth(),
                    rectangle.getY(),
                    rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth(),
                    rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight()));

    return p;
}
```

I have tried this method, but it did not work for rotated rectangles. Also, I do not want to get an array, but the closest point to the start of the line.

Comment: update your question with code you have tried so far.

Comment: how is the rectangle defined (if it is rotated)? by the angle? or just four points (corners)?

Answer (score 0):

However your rectangle is defined, you need to get the four sides.

Then you perform intersection with the line you have as you do.

You will have many if cases: to check where your line is coming from; which point of intersection is left right up down etc

A lot of if-cases.